# Get text without class and from span

Tags: java, jsoup

Hi I could not get the text from html I wanna get this text `This is a test text`

```
<div class="rehou">
       <span class="tlid-t t">
         <span title="" class="">This is a test text</span>
       </span>
    <span class="tlid-t-v" style="" role="button"></span>
</div>
```

My java:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements ele= doc.select("span.tlid-t t");
textass = ele.text();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `span` has the two different classes `tlid-t` and `t`. So if you want to use both classes in your select you should use `span.tlid-t.t` instead of `span.tlid-t t`.

```
Elements ele = doc.select("span.tlid-t.t");
String textass = ele.text();
System.out.println(textass);
```

Which would print `This is a test text`.

But this will select the outer span! If the html gets changed the content of `textass` will be also changing. If you only want to select the text of the inner span you should use `span.tlid-t.t span`.

```
Elements ele = doc.select("span.tlid-t.t span");
String textass = ele.text();
System.out.println(textass);
```

This will also print `This is a test text`.